# Apply aero glass blur to a specific control area in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, pinvoke, wdm

In his book (*Pro WPF in C# 2010 Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 4*) Matthew MacDonald -  writes:

...you can use DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow() to apply the glass effect to a specific region in a
window.

Does this mean I can apply a aero glass effect to a specific controls (or at least an area they occupy)?

Please provide an example on how to do it with C#.

Comment: WPF doesn't use a window for a control.  So yes.  Visit pinvoke.net for the pinvoke declaration.  Is this book really helpful?

Comment: All I have found, are the examples, where you have to feed the Hwnd to DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(). Since, as I already know, WPF controls are not separate windows, I guess the author is wrong in his assumption. This could, by the way, work in Windows Forms windows though =)

Comment: WPF dumps everything in a window into a single HWND.

Comment: @BoltBlock, sure, I know that. It doesn't relate to my question tough =) Is the author of the aforementioned book wrong in his assumption about blurring a windows's region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your intent is to apply DWM implemented blur to a control that would show the content in the window behind it, then no: "This function can only be called on top-level windows.".

You could, however, apply DWM blur to the toplevel window containing the control in the control's area, and see the windows behind it. Check out the P/Invoke signatures for [DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dwmapi/DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow.html), [CreateRectRgn](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/CreateRectRgn.html) and [DeleteObject](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32.DeleteObject) to clean up the blur region.

Comment: How doesn the WvmEnableBlurBeindWindow plays together with CreateRectRgn?

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov: See [MSDN][1]. In short, the `blurBehind` paramater's hRgnBlur is the region to blur, and `CreateRectRgn()` is a simple way to create a region (obviously, a rectangular one). See the GDI API for other HRGN related functions to create non-rectangular regions. [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969508(v=vs.85).aspx